# Custom Core Data Accessors -- setValue:forKey: vs. setPrimitiveValue:forKey:

Tags: ios, macos, core-data

I understand the difference between primitive setter and non-primitive setter (KVO notifications and all that). But if I write my own setValue:forKey: and call setPrimitiveValue:forKey:, do I have to pass it the SAME value? I read the documentation, I googled it but I couldn't find any discussion about this at all.

Edit: Thanks, adpalumbo & Dave FN. You both agree it doesn't have to be the same value. My real question is this. I write my own setter and getter. I then call the setter on a NSManagedObject to change its primitive value, but because of the way the custom getter is written, it's still returning the old value (primitive value has been modified. but if you call the custom getter before and after the modification, you will see no change.). After this I call hasChanges on the NSManagedObjectContext and it returns NO! If I call save on the context, the change will not be saved at all. Any idea? Normal behavior? Potential Core Data bug?

Comment: Quick question in response to your edit, are you calling `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:` in your setter?

Comment: Ah...that's it. I only added didChangeValueForKey: when I had the problem. After adding willChangeValueForKey:, everything works fine. It's not a Core Data bug and it has nothing to do with the custom getter returning the same value. I said I knew the KVO notifications stuff...joke's on me! Thanks so much Dave FN!

Comment: It really is easy to miss one of these calls, as they are added automatically for non-Core Data objects, but not in this case.  I've updated my answer with the proper fix.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to pass the same value to the primitive store.  Just like non-Core Data objects, a setter can assign any value to the instance variable.

Of course, when you do call `valueForKey:` you will get whatever was passed to the primitive store and not what was initially passed to `setValue:forKey:`, unless you also override it and return something else.

**EDIT**
When overriding a Core Data setter, make sure you wrap `setPrimitiveValue:forKey:` with `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:`.

Answer (score 0):

No. That's one of its uses.

You might take a complex object in `setValue:forKey:` and serialize it into an `NSData` or reduce it to some reference identifier before calling `setPrimitiveValue:forKey:`.